# How to get configurable device name

Tags: android

How get Android **device name** which is configurable in device settings? **(Not device model!!!)**

What API provide this field? Does all brands and api levels support it?

[image: Emulator Device Name][image: Xiaomi Device Name]

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a Bluetooth name.

```
public String getLocalBluetoothName(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
    if(name == null){
        System.out.println("Name is null!");
        name = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Check it

Comment: What if device doesn't have bluetooth? I work with specific devices which can doesn't have wifi, bluetooth and etc.
As example I don't have BT on emulator but can configure device name